# A longer pressing the button gives higher value step. [Qt]

Tags: qt, timer, debian, qpushbutton

Is there a widget in Qt, like a button, which depending on the length of press button time, generates a higher change step value?

If not, how to design it?

Comment: There is no such widget but you may create it yourself. Just use keyPressEvent and keyReleaseEvent and measure time and do what you else need.

Comment: This question seems to be about `QPushButton`, so actually key events aren't that useful to get what OP wants. But the principle applies.

Answer (score 0):

No.

To get this functionality, one approach would be to create a helper class, a normal `QObject` subclass, which takes a `QAbstractButton*` as a parameter (possibly as a parent object, so memory management gets taken care of "automatically"). Then this helper object should connect the `pressed()` and `released()` signals, and use for example a `QElapsedTimer` to calculate the length of the button press. And then it should emit custom signals, which do what you want (emit parameterless signal at intervals using `QTimer`? emit one signal at release with time as parameter? up to you).

There are many other possible approaches of course. You could also subclass the button class and implement this in the subclass, or you could sublcass `QAbstractButton`, and allow injecting the desired actual button object to it, and delegating the virtual method calls to that. Or something else.

Answer (score 0):

pressbutton.h

```
#ifndef PRESSBUTTON_H
#define PRESSBUTTON_H

#include <QPushButton>
#include <QElapsedTimer>
#include <QMouseEvent>


class PressButton : public QPushButton
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit PressButton(QWidget *parent=0): QPushButton(parent) {}
    explicit PressButton(const QString &text, QWidget *parent=0) : QPushButton(text,parent) {}
    PressButton(const QIcon& icon, const QString &text, QWidget *parent=0) : QPushButton(icon,text,parent) {}
    ~PressButton() {}

private:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e);
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *e);

signals:
    void mouseTimerClick(qint64 ms);

private:
    QElapsedTimer m_timer;
};

#endif // PRESSBUTTON_H
```

pressbutton.cpp:

```
#include "pressbutton.h"

void PressButton::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    m_timer.start();
    QPushButton::mousePressEvent(e);
}

void PressButton::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{

    emit mouseTimerClick(m_timer.elapsed());
    QPushButton::mousePressEvent(e);
}
```

usage:

```
PressButton* pressButton = new PressButton(this);
connect(pressButton,SIGNAL(mouseTimerClick(qint64)),this,SLOT(onMouseTimerClick(qint64)));
```